# Fetch data from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

how can I fetch data from a google spreadsheet? It's not something like embedding a google doc on a webpage. Suppose, you have a table consisting of 10 rows and 10 columns at google doc. Now, you created a 10x10 table on a PHP webpage. Now you will show the respective values of the cells from that google doc to your php page. It's just like fetching data from a MySQL database and showing them on your web page. But here instead of using a MySQL database, I want to use Google Doc and do the rest. But how can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Google has a REST api for spreadsheets and native apis for many languages.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api

Comment: This API allows you to integrate spreadsheet data into another application. It's not for integrating another application's data into a Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: That's correct and it's what Mahir asked for.  "..show the respective values of the cells from that google doc to your php page".

Answer (score 1):

If your data is the typical table layout (rows of data with a header row) - then you might find this python library helpful:

http://sheetsync.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Temboo provides an SDK library that makes it pretty easy to interact with Google Spreadsheets in multiple languages, including Java/Android, PHP, Ruby, Python, Node.js, and Objective C. There's also an online tool for experimenting with different Google Spreadsheet API calls. Take a look at https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Google/Spreadsheets/

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo)